# Application Pool hang and keeps loading

Tags: php, iis, asp.net-web-api, server, windows-server

I have a problem. We have an in house **server** in our office. It's a super computer server running windows server 2016. Then we developed our own mobile app that's hosted on our in house **server** and we used **PHP** and **IIS** for web services for our mobile app.

Before it was running smoothly and then for some reason sometimes the Application Pool **hangs** like if I access the url **API** it's just keeps loading. I don't have any idea what's the problem. I added **Worker Process** and it works and **I thought that's the solution**. And then after 2 days we encountered same problem.

So every time it happens were down for 5 to 10 minutes. So I need to recycle or switch the **application pool** to another **application pool** so I can **stop** and **start** again the **application pool** that I used for that **API**.

**BTW**, **the app we developed is for uploading of pictures and sending JSON base64 images with maximum of 8 pictures and we have 500 users.**

Do you all guys any idea on how to resolve this problem? I'm struggling right now. Please I need help!

[image]

[image]

Comment: https://blog.lextudio.com/who-should-be-contacted-for-php-on-iis-issues-c80b90bd365 Check if your PHP script hangs in `php-cgi.exe` and then you can see what to do next.

Comment: @LexLi I tried but it shows me blank

Comment: What is blank??